# How to find best set of customers

Tags: integer-programming

I've got a problem with getting optimized solution from this task:

We have n customers, which buy articles from m suppliers. There are much more customers and suppliers on the market. We've got sales data from the m suppliers concernig total market. We want to find a mix from our customers which best represents the market.

Example:

```
Customer   Supplier A  Supplier B  Supplier C  Total
4711       10          30          10           50
4712       20          40          40          100
4713        5          11           9           25
Total      35          81          59          175
%          20%         46%         34%         100%
```

From our supplies we know:

```
Supplier A  Supplier B  Supplier C Total
5000        1500        7000       13500
37%         11%         52%        100%
```

My idea was to find
$$
 f = \min( \sum_{k=0}^m(T_k - S_k)^2)
$$
where
$$
T_k = \sum_{j=0}^n{x_j} * \frac{Customer_{j,k}}{\sum_{i=0}^mCustomer_{i,j}} \hspace{20mm}     x_j = {<0,1>}
$$
and
$$
S_k = \frac{Supplier_k} {\sum_jSupplier_j}
$$

I have lpsolve55.dll, but how can I construct input data for it?

Regards, Gabriel

Comment: Does $x_j=<0,1>$ mean $x_j \in [0,1]$ or $x_j \in \{0,1\}$?

Comment: It means x can be 0 or 1 - I will switch off some customers. It's only example - we have over 100 customers (or even over 400 branches of them) and 7 suppliers